# JQuery: using .text() on an HTML ,the alert displays strange text in the message

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, alert

I got the text of the  tag in the alert, there are strange symbols near the text. Please tell me how can I remove these strange characters? I attach the program code and photo. Thank you.

```js
 $('.blog_content_tags .tags li a').on('click', function () {
    var name = $(this).text();
    alert(name);
 });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ri40W.jpg)

Comment: Could you please add the corresponding HTML? Currently this snippet does nothing

Comment: they helped me solve the problem by the method - trim(). thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those characters are `tab`s.

You can remove them by using spaces in your source or with `trim()`

```js
$('a').on('click', function () {
    var name = $(this).text();
    alert(name);
    alert(name.trim());
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#'>
   test
</a>
```